# Custom Devise: Sessions Controller Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

My custom Devise Sessions controller isn't letting me sign in. I've had several difficulties trying to customize the Devise controllers, but I can't figure out what's going on here.

When I try to sign in, the page (sessions#new) simply re-renders. How can I get my custom controller back to full functionality?

```
# controllers/sessions_controller

class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :store_last_attempted_location
  skip_after_filter  :store_last_successful_location

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end
end
```

My routes

```
#config/routes.rb

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions", :registrations => "registrations"  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the sign in credentials are invalid which is causing the re-rendering. Can you verify that they are correct?  Make sure that you are displaying flash messages in `application.html.erb` because if credentials are invalid then devise sets the error message in flash.

Comment: Correct on both counts, sir, thank you. Not sure how I got deleted, but there it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sign in page is re-rendered after entering the user credentials then it means that  the credentials are invalid which is resulting in the re-rendering. But that should have resulted in a flash message on the re-rendered page as Devise uses flash messages to let the application users know if sign in was successful or failure.

Make sure that you are displaying flash messages in `application.html.erb` as:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Kirti. And heartfelt apologies on the misuse of 'Sir'. You are a gentlewoman and a scholar.