# Devise refresh the same login form after login

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm struggling with this devise programming or configuration error in my app. The thing is is that when I login my application redirects me to the same page and not to the home. Also if I enter a wrong mail or wrong password, no error message comes out.

This is my routes.rb:

```
    Smarket::Application.routes.draw do


      get "home/index"
      resources :tipo_transaccions

       resources :producto_rematados

       resources :provincia_units

       resources :propiedadclases

       resources :compra_venta_normals

       resources :clase_units

       resources :prod_of_necs

       resources :compra_venta_especials

       resources :producto_necesitados

       resources :compra_remates

       resources :notificacions

       resources :comisions

       resources :remates

       resources :pujas

       resources :valors

       resources :usuarios

      resources :propiedads

      resources :regions

      resources :productos

      resources :estado_remates

      resources :ganancia_liquidas

      resources :est_prod_of_necs

      resources :estado_notificacions

      resources :producto_ofertados

      resources :comunas

      resources :condicions


      root :to => "home#index"
      devise_for :usuarios, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations] 
      as :usuario do
         get    "entrar",  to: "devise/sessions#new",         :as => :new_usuario_session
         post   "entrar",  to: "devise/sessions#create",      :as => :usuario_session
         delete "salir", to: "devise/sessions#destroy",     :as => :destroy_usuario_session

          get    "registrarse",  to: "devise/registrations#new",    :as => :new_usuario_registration
          post   "registrarse",  to: "devise/registrations#create", :as => :usuario_registration
    end


    end
```

usuario.rb:

```
    class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
      mount_uploader :avatar, FotoUploader
      include ActiveModel::Validations
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
     self.table_name = 'usuario'
     self.primary_key = 'usuario_id'
     validates :usuario_nombre_usuario, :presence => true
     validates :usuario_rut, :presence => true
     validates :usuario_rut, rut: true
     validates :usuario_nombre, :presence => true
     validates :usuario_apellidopat, :presence => true
     validates :usuario_apellidomat, :presence => true

     validates :email, :presence => true
     validates :usuario_calle, :presence => true
     validates :usuario_numero_calle, :presence => true
     validates :usuario_villa, :presence => true

    belongs_to :usuario
    belongs_to :comuna
```

and app/views/devise/session/new.html.erb:

```
    <div class="login">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="col_1_of_login span_1_of_login">
                <h4 class="title">New Customers</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan</p>
                <div class="button1">
                   <%= link_to "Crear cuenta", new_usuario_registration_path, :style => 'background: #555;
                                                                border:none;
                                                                color: #fff;
                                                                padding: 10px 20px;
                                                                cursor: pointer;
                                                                float: right;
                                                                font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
                                                                outline: none;
                                                                font-size: 1em' %>
                 </div>
                 <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col_1_of_login span_1_of_login">
            <div class="login-title">
                <h4 class="title">Login</h4>
                <div id="loginbox" class="loginbox">
                    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
                        <div>
                            <%= f.label :Email %><br />
                            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :style => 'width:70%' %>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <%= f.label :Contraseña %><br />
                            <%= f.password_field :usuario_contrasena, autocomplete: "off", :style => 'width:70%' %>
                        </div>

                        <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
                        <div>
                            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                            <%= f.label :remember_me, :style => 'float:left; outline: none; padding-right:10px; padding-top:3px; ' %>
                        </div>
                        <% end %>

                        <div><%= f.submit "Login", :style =>    'background: #555;
                                                                border:none;
                                                                color: #fff;
                                                                padding: 10px 20px;
                                                                cursor: pointer;
                                                                float: right;
                                                                font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
                                                                outline: none;
                                                                font-size: 1em'%></div>
                        <% end %><br>

                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Devise: Sessions Controller Failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459288/custom-devise-sessions-controller-failure)

Comment: Have you overriden the session controller or using devise's default sessions controller ?

Answer (score 2):

So for redirecting to other page after sign_in, you need to override devise method :

```
def after_sign_in_path_for resource
  home_path
end
```

For error messages you need to set follow :

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
........
```

Comment: Overriding that method should happen in application_controller.rb. Documentation here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: Or you can override specific controller and put you definition of method . Both of scenarios are correct.